# C++ task Scheduler

Tags: timer, task, scheduler

I want to write a job scheduler in C++ (in Linux environment) which takes in a map of JobID and Job  (std::map) and calls the function associated for the job once the scheduled time is reached.

A Job data structure would look something below:

```
enum Type {Scheduled,Periodic,Event};
typedef int JobId;

class View
{
    void callback(T results);
};

typedef vector<View> Views;

typename <class T>
typedef struct
{
    Type type;
    unsigned int epochTime;
    unsigned int period;
    std::function func;
    int timeout;
    T result;
    Views views;
}Job;

std::map<JobId, Job> Jobs;      //Data structure to add a job schedule
```

Depending on the data in std::map the scheduler should be able to call a function associated with job:

- at a given epochTime (if type is Scheduled)
- periodically. (Eg every XX seconds, if type is Periodic)
- as soon as a new object is added in std::map (if type is Event)

The function associated with the "Scheduled" job is:

```
int scheduledTime(int x,int y)
{
    sleep(5);       //Processing takes 5 seconds
    return (x*y);
}
```

The function associated with the "Periodic" job is:

```
int periodic(int x,int y)
{
    sleep(2);       //Processing takes 2 seconds
    return (x+y);
}
```

The function associated with the "Event" job is:

```
void eventbased()
{
    sleep(15);      //Processing takes 15 seconds
}
```

In the main function, I should be able to create the job schedules as follows: (See comments in main function)

```
int main()
{

    Jobs jobs;
    //Scenario 1 (Scheduled Timer)
    Job job1;
    Views view1;
    job1.type = Scheduled;
    job1.epochTime = 1538390376;
    job1.timeout = 10; 
    job1.period = 0;
    job1.func = scheduledTime;
    job1.views.insert(view1);

    jobs[1] = job1;
```

This should asynchronously execute the function scheduledTime at 1538390376 epoch time. The function add takes 2 seconds to process the result. Once the result is available, the subscribers (here view1) should be notified with callback function.

```
    //Scenario 2 (Periodic Timer)
    Job job2;
    Views view11,view12;
    job2.type = Periodic;
    job2.epochTime = 0;
    job1.timeout = 15; 
    job2.period = 10;
    job2.func = periodic;
    job2.views.insert(view21);
    job2.views.insert(view22);

    jobs[2] = job2;
```

This should asynchronously execute the function periodic every 10 seconds. The function add takes 5 seconds to process the result. Once the result is available, the subscribers (here view21 and view22) should be notified with callback function.

```
    //Scenario 3 (Event Timer)
    Job job3;
    Views view31,view32;
    job3.type = Event;
    job3.epochTime = 0;
    job1.timeout = 20; 
    job3.period = 5;
    job3.func = eventbased;
    job3.views.insert(view31);
    job3.views.insert(view32);

    jobs[3] = job3; 
}
```

This should asynchronously execute the function eventbased after 5 seconds. The function eventbased takes 15 seconds to execute after which the subscribers (here view31 and view32) should be notified with their callback function.

Note:Jobs can be added/deleted/updated dynamically without needing to restart the existing running scheduler.

Comment: You could start an open source project with those ideas!
If you need an organization on GitHub, you are welcome on https://github.com/cpp-projects-showcase . But feel free to create the one you want.
Also, you may be already aware of a similar initiatiive: https://github.com/dougbinks/enkiTS